# Working with JSON response from jQuery (Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to get data from the JSON from a http request. I'm returned 10 objects which each contain several keys. I can access a specific object but can't get to the key.

This code get me an object in the console and I can see each key and value.

```
  $.getJSON(flurryAPI,
format: "json"
).done (data) ->
  console.log data.event[0]
```

How do I access a specific key? e.g. id

This is what I see in the console with the above code:

```
Object {@usersLastWeek: "0", @usersLastMonth: "0", @usersLastDay: "0", @totalSessions: "10", @totalCount: "10"…}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data.event[0]` is your object with the properties then:

```
console.log( data.event[0]['@totalCount'] );
console.log( data.event[0]['@usersLastWeek'] );
```

Because of the `@` in the property names, you have to use the array notation `[]` instead of the object `.` notation.

Comment: That gives me undefined.

Comment: Added that to the question